# Why do these two code snippets produce different plots?

Tags: pine-script

I've created a few scripts and experiments in pine. Try as I might I cannot get my head around what I would call some of pinescripts "idiosyncrasies". Here is one I would greatly appreciate an explanation of:

Exhibit A:

```
len = input(14, 'length', input.integer)
highrsi = rsi(high, len)
lowrsi = rsi(low, len)
val = rsi(close, len) > 50 ? highrsi : lowrsi
plot(val)
```

Exhibit B:

```
len = input(14, 'length', input.integer)
val = rsi(close, len) > 50 ? rsi(high, len) : rsi(low, len)
plot(val)
```

In any other language, these two pieces of code would be equivalent since all I did was store the result of the rsi() function in a couple of variables in exhibit A.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pine runtime is very different from that of normal languages. Many function calls like `rsi()` need to be executed on every bar to return proper results, which is not the case in your Exhibit B. While the code is syntactically correct and compiles, it will not work properly.

See [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html#execution-of-pine-functions-and-historical-context-inside-function-blocks) for a detailed explanation from the usrman.

Comment: Thank you :). This does make more sense now. In the second example, the series rsi(high, len) and rsi(low, len) may not get run on every bar since they are hidden behind an if branch, causing "missing" values in the series.